# Facebook infinite Loop on login

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, oauth

```
 var login = false;
 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
              console.log('connected');
              login=true;
                // the user is logged in and connected to your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
          }
          else{
              FB.login(function(response) {
               if (response.authResponse) {
                 console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                   console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                   if(login===false)
                   {
                       window.open("http://www.facebook.com/EnergyZuerich/app_332399760133904", "_top");
                   }
                   //window.location.href=window.location.href;
                   //FB.logout(function(response) {
                     //console.log('Logged out.');
                   //});
                 });
               } else {
                 console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
               }    
             }, {scope: 'email'});
          }});
```

This authentication works for me and for the most other people in my company except for one person, where it causes an infite loop.

The Login Popup Show's up for a short Time (he already is Authenticated). Then the popup goes away, the Site refreshes and it begins from the start.

I tested it with IE, Firefox and Chrome and had no Problems. He is trying it with Firefox..

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: This have nothing to do with PHP, is Javascript!

Comment: i'am returning the Login data to php. But i removed the tag since it isn't relevant for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user probably has cookies disabled.

Comment: True story.. I should have thought about that.^^